# rails using tus protocol and shrine occurred error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shrine

I tested tus protocol with shrine.

and I followed tutorial [this link](https://twin.github.io/resumable-file-uploads-in-ruby)

But on create action(app/controllers/albums_controller.rb) ocuured error

`` undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? clone ``

On debugging error occured this line

https://github.com/janko-m/shrine/blob/master/lib/shrine.rb#L721

How to fix my code?

My github code is

https://github.com/ggomagundan/shrine-rails-example

initializer : config/initializers/shrine.rb

uploader: app/uploader/image_uploader.rb

appliationjs: app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: Could you be more specific? What does `on create controller` mean?

Comment: @Vasile it means ``app/controller/albums_controller.rb`` create action

Comment: I uploaded an image and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: @Vasile Really?.. :( ok. I try test one more time

Comment: There was an bug in Shrine, where if the storage raised an error while attempting to download the file, Shrine would fail with this error, shadowing the storage error. This is now [fixed](https://github.com/janko-m/shrine/commit/da2d4ab105777bdea5792e8742e1968cd69692c8). Try using the Shrine master, and let me know what error do you get now (preferrably with a stack trace).

Comment: @janko-m Thx :) Now working~